# Insuficient Parameter Pass To the Command SQlite Unknown Error How Can I Solve This...Please

Tags: c#, sqlite

```
cmd = con.CreateCommand();

cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO Trip_Info 
    (Id,Date,CompanyName,FromTrip,ToTrip,TankerNo,Product,
    Size,ShortKg,ShortAllow,LRNo,ShortBal,NetWtMt,TotalAmt,DriverId,
    DepartureTime,ArrivelTime,DriverMoney,Maintainance,PayingMode,
    ChekNo,PayingAmnt,RemainingAmnt,CompanyId)
    VALUES(@Id,@Date,@CompanyName,@FromtTrip,@ToTrip,@TankerNo,@Product,
    @Size,@ShortKg,@ShortAlw,@LRNo,@ShortBal,@NetWtMt,@TotalAmt,@DriverId,
    @DepartureTime,@ArrivelTime,@DriverMoney,@Maintainance,@PayingMode,
    @CheckNo,@PayingAmnt,@RemainingAmnt,@CompanyId)";


cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Id", Convert.ToInt32(txtid.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Date", txtDate.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@CompanyName", xtCompanyName.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@FromTrip", txtFrom.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ToTrip", txtTo.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@TankerNo", txtTankerNo.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Product", txtProduct.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Size", Convert.ToDecimal(txtsize.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ShortKg", Convert.ToDecimal(txtShortKg.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ShortAlw", Convert.ToDecimal(txtShortAllow.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@LRno", Convert.ToDecimal(txtLRno.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ShortBal", Convert.ToDecimal(txtShortBal.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@NetWtMt", Convert.ToDecimal(txtNet.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@TotalAmt", Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@DriverId", Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@DepartureTime", txtDeparture.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@ArrivelTime", txtArrivel.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@DriverMoney", Convert.ToDecimal(txtDriverMoney.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Maintainance",txtMaintanance.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@PayingMode",txtPayingMode.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@CheckNo",txtCheckNo.Text)); 
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@PayingAmnt", Convert.ToDecimal(txtPayingAmnt.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(newSQLiteParameter("@RemainingAmnt",Convert.ToDecimal(txtRemainingAmnt.Text)));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@CompanyId",Convert.ToInt32(txtCompanyName.SelectedValue.ToString())));
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Trip Created !!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.None, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have a typo:

@FromTrip <> @FromtTrip

Cheers Thomas